# What is the meaning ウソ & 誰向 in this sentence

Tags: katakana, homophonic-kanji

I've been wondering about the different usage for USO in Japanese.

Recently I bumped in this little text:

> 多分いつも以上に**誰向**けだか分からない内容になってます　自分の好きなものに**ウソ**をついてはいけない松野で！

My only issue here is with 誰向 and ウソ.

As for the first one I know the meaning of both Kanji, it's just I can't make up what they mean together.

As for USO usually it would be something about "false" information but well I'm not too sure here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding the fist part is to know what 送り仮名 are part of the verb and not. In this case, け is part of the word.

> 誰向け
>
> to whom

from [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/214895/meaning/m0u/%E5%90%91%E3%81%91/)

> む・ける【向ける】
>
> １ その方向に正面が位置するようにする。ある方向を向かせる。「視線を―・ける」「背を―・ける」「マイクを―・ける」「怒りを他人に―・ける」

---

> ウソ
>
> lie

The word ウソ is normally used together with つく to mean the verb "lie".

from [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/18986/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BD/)

> うそ【×嘘】
>
> １ 事実でないこと。また、人をだますために言う、事実とは違う言葉。偽 (いつわ) り。「―をつく」「この話に―はない」

Comment: Adding some more background : "--向け", like "子供向け", "初心者向け", "個人向け" (as opposed to 法人向け) is typically used to mean "aimed at"/"intended for"/"suitable to".